# Replace a number in var with another number

Tags: php

I've got a `var` with the following content: `+5 cars`.

Now I want to take the numeric character, divide it by 3 and replace the current number with the new number. But I have no idea how to approach this. I've Googled for this and it lead me to `preg_replace` but it can't really be that difficult, can it?

Now obviously, 5 can't be divided by 3, that's why I want it to `round()`.  If anybody knows a way to accomplish this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What's "that difficult" on using `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Give it a try and if there is any error post it so that we can help

Comment: @HonzaHaering there are so many formats and I don't always know what to do after I've added it.

Comment: @AmanRawat I can't post error's since I've no idea how to approach this in the first place.

Comment: If the number needs to be manipulated, why are you storing it in a string with other characters?

Comment: *"Now obviously, 5 can't be divided by 3"* - Well, probably not "evenly", but sure it can. You'll just end up with 1.66666666666666 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `str_replace` ([reference](http://php.net/str_replace)) and `intval` ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)) (and as you mentioned [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)):

```
$test = '+5 cars';
$test = str_replace(intval($test),round($test/3),$test);
echo $test;
```

Would output:

```
+2 cars
```

Comment: If I were to place the output in a new `var`, should I do the following: `$newVar = str_replace(intval($test),round($test/3),$test);`?

Comment: I got it working. Thank you for this neat one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it as integer and replace by the result of division:

```
$s = "+5 cars";
$num = intval($s); // or $num = (int) $s;
$s = str_replace($num, round($num/3), $s);
echo $s;
//+2 cars
```

Or, using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/',$s, $matches);
$s = str_replace($matches[0][0], round($matches[0][0]/3), $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempr=(explode(" ",$varname));
$num = $tempr[0] ; 
$newnum = $tempr[0]/5;
$newvar=$newnum." ".$tempr[1];
```

that will work hopefully